# Controller issue: undefined local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

A controller method includes:

```
  @organization = Organization.find(params[:description])
  check_expiration_date(@organization)
  if @organization.update_attributes(subscription: true,
                                     actioncode: session[:actioncode_id],
                                     subs_exp_date: expiration_date)
  ...

  private
  def check_expiration_date(org)
    expiration_date = Time.zone.now + 366.days
  end
```

On the development server this generates the error below, referring to the line `subs_exp_date: expiration_date`:

```
undefined local variable or method `expiration_date' for #<OrganizationsController:0x007f36cd01d2a8>
```

Any ideas what might be causing this error? My idea was that check_expiration_date is executed first and thus sets the variable expiration_date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
  if @organization.update_attributes(subscription: true,
                                     actioncode: session[:actioncode_id],
                                     subs_exp_date: check_expiration_date(@organization))
```

If you see your code, `expiration_date` is a variable inside method `check_expiration_date` which limits its scope only to that method. Hence you cannot use variable `expiration_date` outside `check_expiration_date`.

Other way can be defining expiration date as an instance variable. Here:

```
def check_expiration_date(org)
    @expiration_date = Time.zone.now + 366.days
end
```

and then

```
if @organization.update_attributes(... subs_exp_date: @expiration_date)
```

Key here is:

> Contrast the scope of a local variable with that of an instance
>   variable: the instance variable is bound to the specific instance of
>   the class. By binding itself to the entire object, an instance
>   variable makes itself available to every method of the object.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

Change this code:

```
check_expiration_date(@organization)
```

to:

```
expiration_date = check_expiration_date(@organization)
```

**Solution 2:**

Change:

```
  def check_expiration_date(org)
    expiration_date = Time.zone.now + 366.days
  end
```

to:

```
def check_expiration_date(org)
  @expiration_date = Time.zone.now + 366.days
end
```

and then:

```
if @organization.update_attributes(subscription: true,
                                     actioncode: session[:actioncode_id],
                                     subs_exp_date: @expiration_date)
```

Reason: You're trying to access `expiration_date`, which is a local variable whose scope is limited to `check_expiration_date` method and hence ruby is looking for a method instead of a variable. So, you need to make it an instance variable or create a local variable from the returning object of `check_expiration_date` method to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you set local variable `expiration_date`, it is visible only in current scope defined by method body. If you want to make this variable 'visible' also after method execution, you can set it instance variable:

```
@expiration_date = Time.zone.now + 366.days
```

and use it:

```
subs_exp_date: @expiration_date
```

For more info about Ruby variable scopes, you can go here:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope

or here:

[Difference between various variables scopes in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495098/difference-between-various-variables-scopes-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a local variable instead of instance variable. Its about variable scope. There are 2 options to get proper value for  **subs_exp_date**

1. Convert local variable to instance variable

> @expiration_date = Time.zone.now + 366.days

2. Another option to call method directly

> subs_exp_date: check_expiration_date(@organization)