# Issue calling method in short example

Tags: ruby

In the following how should I call this method properly?

Here's the exmaple where I try to call randomMethod() and an error throws saying it is undefined.

```
def randomMethod()

  rand1 = rand(2)
  if rand1 == 1

    rand2 = rand(1..25)
    puts rand2
    puts ""

  else
    rand2 = 0
    puts rand2
    puts ""
  end
end

x = 99
while x > 0
  randomMethod()
  x - rand2 
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access local method variables from outside the method itself:

```
def my_method
  @val1 = 1
  val2 = 2
end

my_method #=> 2 returns the value of the last line of the method
@val1 #=> 1 (or you get nil unless you call my_method before)
val2 #=> undefined local variable or method `val2`
```

Check this post [Difference between various variables scopes in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495098/difference-between-various-variables-scopes-in-ruby)

---

You could rewrite your method like this:

```
def random_method
  return rand(1..25) if rand(2) == 1
  0 # return value unless the condition above
end
```

Note that it doesn't assure that 50% of the times returns a number between 1 and 25, but the probability is 50%.

Then use [Kernel#loop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) for the iteration, you need to decrement `x`:

```
x = 99
loop do
  puts "x = #{x}"
  x -= random_method # decrement x by the value returned by random_method
  break if x <= 0
end
```

Answer (score 8):

```
#use this kind of convention about name of function
def random_method()
    #always initialize your varialble first before implement to avoid errors
    rand1 = rand(2)
    rand2 = 0

    if rand1 == 1
      rand2 = rand(1..25)
    end

    #don't repeat yourself
    puts rand2
    puts ""

    #pick a return just to make sure you do not mistaken
    return rand2
end


x = 99
while x > 0
    rand2=random_method()
    x - rand2
    x = x - 1
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't return the rand2 value from the `randomMethod` method and also you haven't received as well. I modified your program, check it now.

```
def randomMethod()

  rand1 = rand(2)
  if rand1 == 1

    rand2 = rand(1..25)
    puts rand2
    puts ""

  else
    rand2 = 0
    puts rand2
    puts ""
  end
  rand2
end

x = 99
while x > 0
  rand2=randomMethod()
  x - rand2
  x-=1
end
```

Comment: That fixed the error i was getting. Now what im trying to solve is the infinite loop if anyone has a suggestion.

Comment: @Amadan Actually I took his program and modified the problematic area. Now I have updated.

Comment: @gingervitiis Updated with `x-=1`. you can check now.

Comment: Im glad its functional now. However the goal of this program is to subtract the number generated in line 6 and subtract it from x. So when x hits 0 thats when the random numbers are shown in the console. For example generating a 25 4 times would end the program because 100 > 99